# AddBindings in Ninject and null repository in Controller class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ninject.web.mvc

In my `NinjectDependencyresolver` I have this:

```
public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
{
    this.kernel = kernelParam;
    AddBindings();
}

private void AddBindings()
{
    kernel.Bind<IProductsRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
}
```

and then in my `controller` class I have this:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductsRepository repository;
    public int PageSize = 4;

    public ProductController()
    {

    }

    public ProductController(IProductsRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }
```

The problem is that the `repository` is `null`
Also If I add a break point to the `AddBinsings() method`, it doesn't get hit before going to the controller, `controller` gets hit but `AddBindings()` does not.
So does it mean it is a problem with my `Ninject`?

**ALSO**: I added the `parameter less constructor` of `ProductController` after getting this error:

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object
```

I don't think I need that constructor, but if I remove it I get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have also called it in `Gloabal.ashx.cs` file

Answer (score 1):

I would start by removing the constructor to ProductController that has no parameters.  This will force ninject to use the constructor with IProductsRepository.

As for the binding part, we have the binding taking place inside the NinjectWebCommon.cs file.  Here is our sample:

```
   public static class NinjectWebCommon
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof (OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof (NinjectHttpModule));
            Bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            Bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {   
            var kernel = new StandardKernel(new VBNinjectModule());
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);

            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            BindWebSpecificServices(kernel);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new VBNinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }

        public static void BindWebSpecificServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IUserHelper>()
                  .To<UserHelper>()
                  .InRequestScope();

            kernel.Bind<IRoleWebService>()
                .To<RoleWebService>()
                .InRequestScope();
}
```

Comment: Yeah the Parameterless constructor wasn't originally in my code, I had to add it because of this error: "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" I took it now, now getting that error.

Comment: "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" means that it's not binding ninject to IProductsRepository.  Take a look at my NinjectWebCommon and compare it to your own.

Comment: oh ok, so I added kernel.Bind<IProductsRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>(); to the CreateKernel() method, looks like you are binding them there too.